# call code behind function from javascript with parameters

Tags: javascript, vb.net, function, parameters, ascx

> I have code Behind function in **`.ascx`** (**`User Control`**) as follows

```
Public Function GetCity(strCountry As [String]) As String
    Dim strCity As String = String.Empty
    If strCountry = "USA" Then
        strCity = "NewYork"
    Else
        strCity = "OtherCity"
    End If
    Return strCity
End Function
```

I want to call this function from JavaScript hover event. I have tried the following method but it does not work for function with **`parameter`**

```
 function popup(e) {
        var params = e.getAttribute('alt'); 
        var s = <%=GetCity() %>
    }
```

How to pass the javascript arguments to code behind function while it calling from JavaScript side.

I am not able to use PageMethods since **Page Methods don't work in either Master Pages or User Controls.**.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can setting value in a hidden field in javascript. Create post back button have css `display:none` have server event and call generate postback function of post back button. Hope this help!

You create a simple page and dragdrop link button from toolbox. you can view html source code below

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<script>

</script>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default2.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTQ1OTQ0MTYyOWRkuWlHCHAXVuntHm4idSdrbGyB4bo1plZ25doIF2bKALo=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKls9rrAgLM9PumD51kLQ9HHdzfMdVDeQCyvUBdqVdENTp5zu30+p/t+upk" />
</div>
    <a id="LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">LinkButton</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You see it create function __doPostBack . And a link is not postback so it generate html to  `<a id="LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">LinkButton</a>` so you can create this LinkButton have server event you need, hiden the link css display:none set value for hiden field in js when hover  and call js __doPostBack('LinkButton1','') to server postback process with your hidden fiel value. I don't show all code. You can try it . Other way you can you ajax to call code behind [call code behind ajax](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180355/Calling-a-code-behind-function-from-JavaScript)

Comment: I have some idea for you, you can try